# Finding the domain and Range of a composite functions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

if `f(x)` and `g(x)` are well defined functions and `f∘g(x)` exists, is the following generalization true for all scenarios (i.e. when domain of either or both `f(x)` and `g(x)` is restricted):

Domain of `f∘g(x)` = Domain of `g(x)` ∩ domain of `f∘g(x)`

Range of `f∘g(x)` =  Range of `f(x)` ∩ range of `f∘g(x)`

### If the above is true, how do we derive the identities?

Edit:

I want to find the domain and range of the composite function \begin{equation}f \circ g(x)\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2-4, x\in R, x > 8
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(x) = 2x-2,x\in R, x > 6
\end{equation}

$\begin{equation}
D_{fg} = D_{g} \cap D_{f\circ g(x)}
\end{equation}$ = $\begin{equation}
(x>8) \cap (x\in R)
\end{equation}$ = $\begin{equation}
x>8
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
R_{fg} = R_{f} \cap R_{f\circ g(x)}
\end{equation}$ = $\begin{equation}
(y>60)\cap (y\geq -4)
\end{equation}$ = $\begin{equation}
y>60
\end{equation}$

1. is my approach correct?
2. If so, can this be generalized for all well defined composite functions?
3. if I want to prove that "Domain of `f∘g(x)` = Domain of `g(x)` ∩ domain of `f∘g(x)` and Range of `f∘g(x)` =  Range of `f(x)` ∩ range of `f∘g(x)`", how do I approach it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you tell us what you've done so far? And what issues are you facing to answer the question? Also $f(x)$ is an element. So speaking of domain or range of $f(x)$ doesn't make sense. Can you update your question taking into account those points? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question based on your input.